# How to Edit and Update particular field data in MySQL using Nodejs sequelize using findById?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, angular, sequelize.js

This is the error--

```js
TypeError: Customer.findById is not a function
    at exports.findById (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-mySql\app\controller\customer.controller.js:25:12)at Layer.handle [as handle_request(E:\Angular7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs
    -MySql\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at next (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-MySql\node_modules\express\
    lib\router\route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-MySql\node_module
    s\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs
    -MySql\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-MySql\node_modules\express\lib\ro
    uter\index.js:281:22
        at param (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-MySql\node_modules\express
    \lib\router\index.js:354:14)
        at param (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-MySql\node_modules\express
    \lib\router\index.js:365:14)
        at Function.process_params (E:\Angular 7\anguar_NodeJs_Mysql\NodeJs-MySql\no
    de_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:410:3)
```

[I used this Link example](https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-6/angular-6-httpclient-node-js-express-sequelize-mysql-get-post-put-delete-restapis#Angular_6_HttpClient)

Comment: Please provide sequelize version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of sequelize version 5. findById is removed and the official alternative is findByPk.

Refer [sequelize migration doc](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/master/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md)